# How to use Segno to generate a QR code on the fly in python

Tags: python, qr-code

How can I use the `Segno` qrcode python library to generate a QR Code on the fly to show it on a web page.

For example, exporting it as an SVG:

```py
import segno
qr = segno.make('Up Jumped the Devil')
svgvar = qr.export_as_svg()
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import segno
# var contains a SVG data URI
var = segno.make('Up Jumped the Devil').svg_data_uri()
```

Here `var` contains the QR code as data URI:

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns[...]
```

which can be used to embed the code directly into any HTML img, or even a browser.

**Another option**:
Write the SVG into a binary *buffer* instead of a file:

```
import segno 
import io
buff = io.BytesIO()
segno.make('Up Jumped the Devil').save(buff, kind="svg")
# Returns the SVG output
buff.getvalue()
```

`buff` contains the complete SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="33" height="33" class="segno"><path[...]</svg>
```

The output cannot be used directly within a HTML page, but you can omit the XML declaration and SVG namespace:

```py
segno.make('Up Jumped the Devil').save(buff, kind="svg", xmldecl=False, svgns=False)
```

Result of `buff.getvalue()`:

```xml
<svg width="33" height="33" class="segno"><path[...]</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks user11751870 . I actually using jQuery.qrcode now

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in my **views.py** to generate a QR code dynamically.

```
import segno
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from .models import MyModel

class QRCodeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "my_template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        param = self.kwargs['param'] # this is how to grab something from the url pattern

        # scale=10 changes size of saved image
        # svg_data_uri (or png_data_uri) is saved in memory and easily put in html <img src='uri'>
        # .make_qr forces a non-micro QR code
        qr_code = segno.make_qr(f"MY {param} DATA").svg_data_uri(scale=10)
        
        context['qrcode'] = qr_code
        return context
```

Now I can access this in my **template.html**

```
<img src="{{ qrcode }}" ...>
```

I prefer this to using a buffer because there is no need to convert to/from Byte/Image, no other libraries needed.